# "Mathematics is the science of the infinite"

Tags: co.combinatorics, mathematical-philosophy, gm.general-mathematics, discrete-mathematics

The title is the first sentence of Hermann Weyl's 1930 essay, 
"[Levels of Infinity](http://peterpesic.com/levels-of-infinity/)."
He focuses on

> "the distinction between actuality and potentiality, between
>   *Being and Possibility*."

He opines

> "the impossibility of grasping the continuum as a fixed being,"

and concludes his essay with the claim that

> "we can only represent the completed infinite in the symbol."

My question is:

> ***Q***. To what extent is the claim that "Mathematics is the science of the infinite"
>   accepted or justifiable by mathematicians today?
>   Is his essay a relic of the period in which he penned it, 
>   or does it express a generally accepted viewpoint today?

I ask in light of the modern "rise of combinatorics"<sup>1</sup> 
and of discrete mathematics.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>[Richard Guy: The rise of combinatorics (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RkAvoSC6fs).

<sup>2</sup>
Ralston, Anthony. "The decline of calculus—The rise of discrete mathematics." In *Mathematics Tomorrow*, pp. 213-220. Springer, New York, NY, 1981.
([Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-8127-3_21).)

Comment: Voted to close... **Primarily opinion-based**.  If we do this one, then we could ask about  "Mathematics: The Science of Patterns" (Keith Devlin), and then "What is Mathematics?" (Courant & Robbins), and then "What is Mathematics Really?" (Reuben Hersch).   So ... this is not a topic for a question here.  Perhaps requesting references about "what is mathematics" may be OK.

Comment: So the underlying question in the light of other MO Qs you've asked is perhaps to what extent can continuum methods be legitimately supplanted by discrete methods--a reversal of the historical evolution of the calculus?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere a traditional formula: the science of number and space (which I think has resonances going back to ancient Greece: the quaternity "arithmetic, geometry, music, astronomy" seems very suggestive). Then there's Thurston, who seems more modern: “the theory of formal patterns” (see his essay "Proof and Progress..."). But permit me to remind that MO is not well-adapted to discussion-y questions, interesting though this one could be for a discussion. [IMHO Weyl's description sounds much too limited.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a fairly straightforward answer to this question coming from [reverse mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics). According to Wikipedia, "finitistic reductionism" is represented by the system WKL${}_0$, and reverse math people know a lot about what mathematics can be done in WKL${}_0$ and what mathematics requires substantially stronger systems. Whether WKL${}_0$ corresponds to finitism exactly may be debatable, but in any case we know a lot about what can and can't be done around this level.

To answer the question directly, I think it's fair to say that most ordinary mathematics can be done in WKL${}_0$, and nearly all of it can be done in ACA${}_0$, which is predicative if not finitistic (although full predicativism [goes substantially further than this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03543)).

Comment: By "predictive", did you mean "predicative"?

Comment: WKL asserts existence of infinite sets...

Comment: Surely $RCA_0$ is the realm of finitism?

Comment: I think the idea is that WKL${}_0$ is supposed to be finitistically "reducible" because it is conservative over PRA for $\Pi^0_1$ sentences. In other words, we can trust it for the sentences we care about and just play a game with other sentences. Yes, I agree that RCA${}_0$ is broadly considered to be finitistically acceptable.